# Shapefile uploaded to GeoServer via REST API doesn't get published

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, geoservices-rest-api

I'm using PHP's cURL to upload Shapefiles to my GeoServer. It works fine but, sometimes, some of the Shapefiles got correctly uploaded but they aren't published automatically. Other times they do (thats what I want).

If I try to manually publish one layer uploaded this way I got two errors:

[image: Errors on publish]

I see in the config that my native SRS shows as `UNKNOWN` and the declared SRS is empty (I'm sorry for the screenshot, my GeoServer is automatically configured in Catalan and I can't set the language to English):

[image: SRS Config]

I guess the problem comes from the `.PRJ` file in my Shapefile, but I don't know if that's true and if there's really an error there...

A sample `.PRJ` on my files:

```
PROJCS[
    "ETRS89_UTM_zone_31N",
    GEOGCS[
        "GCS_ETRS_1989",
        DATUM[
            "D_ETRS_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]
        ],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]
    ],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",3],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]
]
```

My correct SRS should be EPSG:3043 (or the equivalent EPSG:25831). Is there something wrong with my `.PRJ`?

---

**UPDATE**

After Andrea's answer, all of my uploaded Shapefiles get the correct SRS but in some cases they aren't still published due to the `Field 'latLonBoundingBox' is required` error. So,

Is there a way to force the calculation of the BoundingBox at upload time (best option) or after upload with another API call (not that good...)?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong, but GeoServer won't recognize that's EPSG:3043 because the WKT lacks the code and it's using ESRI own projection and datum names (instead of the EPSG ones). Set this in the prj instead:

> PROJCS["ETRS89 / TM31", 
>     GEOGCS["ETRS89", 
>       DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989", 
>         SPHEROID["GRS 1980", 6378137.0, 298.257222101, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]], 
>         TOWGS84[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
>         AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]], 
>       PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
>       UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
>       AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
>       AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
>       AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]], 
>     PROJECTION["Transverse Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]], 
>     PARAMETER["central_meridian", 3.0], 
>     PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
>     PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
>     PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0], 
>     PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
>     UNIT["m", 1.0], 
>     AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
>     AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
>     AUTHORITY["EPSG","3043"]]

You can use http://prj2pepsg.org to translate ESRI WKTs to EPSG ones.

GeoServer 2.11 (to be released in March) got better at figuring out ESRI own WKT names and *migth* work without you touching the prj file. You can give it a try by downloading a nightly build here: http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/master/

Comment: With your PRJ all of my Shapefiles got the right SRS (*thank you!*) but some of them aren't still published due to the BoundingBox issue... I've updated my question.

Comment: Uh, unusure... just a guess, might it be that they have the wrong SRS and GeoServer cannot reproject the native bounding box to lat/lon?

Comment: Do you mean that the Shapefiles aren't really in EPSG:3043? Mmm... if I force the calculation of the BoundingBox on the GeoServer interface it works fine and I can publish and preview the layer without problem.

Comment: Then I have no clue, sorry. Maybe best do switch the discussion to geoserver-users and share some sample data, as it's becoming a debugging problem instead of a straight question/answer